# capitalizing input moves cursor to the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Capitalizing the content of an input tag in React makes the cursor move to the end of the text.
Any idea how to fix it or how it can be done in another way to avoid this problem?

**Please check the [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/muscaiu/pen/mLPXQB?editors=0010)**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: ''
  }

  handleInputchange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: this.handleCapitalize(e.target.value) })
  }

  handleCapitalize = (str) => {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input onChange={this.handleInputchange} value={this.state.variableName} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happen because the text in `variableName` **was completely replaced after typing.**
You can work around this by manually **managing DOM selection using a ref.** Or if it is possible for project tasks play around with some styling your input.

This problem has been discuss there, on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9894).